# Passing MySQL through Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a simple registration form that uses jQuery and Ajax to validate the user input.  When the Ajax tries to do the server side validation of the e-mail address (for example) and connect to the database, it doesn't return a result via `$msg`.

```
function checkUser () {
    $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'"); 
    $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

    if($match > 0) {
        $msg .= 'Username already in use, please try another.';
    } 
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
function send(datastr) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./scripts/addmember.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#errordiv").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#errordiv").html(html);
            //setTimeout('$("#errordiv").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey just if you are wondering why the down votes (not me) this is terrible application design passing SQL through js / Ajax . You may want to reconsider your design.

Comment: Without addmember.php it is very hard to give anything but general suggestions.

Comment: @DamenTheSifter and @ anyone who downvoted for that reason: the title is wrong. There's no SQL being passed through Ajax. The first snippet is *PHP*. It's probably not even vulnerable to SQL injection, since we see only the variable `$username`. You're escaping it, right?

Comment: That code *screams* SQL injection.

Comment: As Chris says, you should be aware of SQL injection attacks - $username is totally unescaped and someone more nefarious than I could put raw SQL commands to execute in there. See http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html . What you are doing there is dangerous and bad in a very direct sense.

Answer (score 3):

In your `checkUser()` function you're using `$msg` and `$username`, which aren't defined. You either left those out or you are very new to programming.

In PHP, variables usually have only a single "scope". This means that a variable `$msg` isn't accessible in a function, unless you define it there.

In javascript, this is valid :

```
var msg = "";
function appendToMsg(text) {
    msg += text;
}
appendToMsg("test");
```

In PHP, this is not:

```
$msg = "";
function appendToMsg($text) {
    $msg += $text;
}
appendToMsg("test");
```

This will throw a notice *PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: msg*. The function `appendToMsg` will only know `$text`, not `$msg`.

The correct PHP representation of the little JavaScript code is:

```
$msg = "";
function appendToMsg(&$msg, $text) {
    $msg += $text;
}
appendToMsg($msg, "test");
```

More on variable scopes:

- [PHP: Variable scope (PHP.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
- [Scope (computer science) (wikipedia.org)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` the output:

```
echo 'Username already in use, please try another.';
```

Answer (score 0):

after you are setting text for the $msg variable, write this:

```
echo $msg;
```